# Would God take his Spirit from me (Psalm 51:11)?

Tags: psalms

Psalm 51:11
Do not cast me from your presence or take your Holy Spirit from me.

Is it possible that God would take his Holy Spirit from us?

Answer (score 2):

In Hebrew Tanakh [Tehillim (Psalms) 51:13] "Do not take Your Holy Spirit from me" ( וְר֥וּחַ קָ֜דְשְׁךָ֗ אַל־תִּקַּ֥ח מִמֶּֽנִּי ). - Taking the Holy Spirit (Ruach Qadesh) from a person = being 'Brought into Temptation'. [Matthew 6:13]

- If you keep reading - [Tehillim (Psalms) 51:12] " Create for me a pure heart, O God, and renew a steadfast spirit within me. " (לֵ֣ב טָ֖הוֹר בְּרָא־לִ֣י אֱלֹהִ֑ים וְר֥וּחַ נָ֜כ֗וֹן חַדֵּ֥שׁ בְּקִרְבִּֽי). * It means help us keep a pure heart.

Yes - It is possible to lose our purity in context to Hebrew (Ivri, עִבְרִ֑י ) theology.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to have the spirit taken away in the way it was in the Old Testament.

JOHN 14:16 *And I will pray the Father, and He will give you another Helper, that He may **abide with you forever***

In the Old Testament, the Holy Spirit could only come **‘on’** man. And even then, only some, example Kings, Prophets, and even then, ‘at times’.
And - In Old Testament times, his presence could/would be ‘lifted’ off or away - dependant on what man ‘did’.

Where as we can have Him, the Holy Spirit, **’in’** us.

Jesus needed to ‘die’ so that we (our body, the temple of the Holy Spirit.) could be ‘cleansed’ - because it needed to be cleansed before it could be used. And, our righteousness, our ‘cleanliness’ Is not dependant on anything we do. It was/is dependant on what Jesus did.

Comment: this answer ignore the many times that people were told not to send the Holy Spirit away, Heb 6:4-6, 1 Thess 5:19, Eph 4:30, Acts 7:51, 2 Peter 2:21, Matt 12:31, 32, Mark 3:28, 29, and Luke 12:8-10, etc.

Comment: (1) Your references to Mat, Mark, Luke re: Blasphemy, are Old Testament examples (Yes, in the NT, but pre Jesus’s death.) I covered that.
(2) Quench, grieve, resist the spirit. Yes, believers can ‘ignore’, grieve the Holy Spirit that’s ‘in them’, but that doesn’t mean it ‘leaves’ them. (ROM 8:9, Eph 1:13-14).

Comment: Fascinating and "innovative" exegesis especially since the future tense is used in those references.  But you may believe what you will.   According to your thesis no matter how bad someone become they cannot loose the Holy Spirit.  That sounds like extreme Calvinism to me.

Comment: Yes, extreme Calvinism.  It is presumptive to say that people having the Holy Spirit in the O.T. was somehow different than in the N.T.  "The spirit came on" in the O.T. means the same thing as "Received the Holy Spirit" in the N.T.  Just different wording is all.  David knew he was in danger of losing God's Holy Spirit which was "in" him (dwelling in him), and basically what he was saying to God was "Please give me another chance."